# Is it possible for the UK to be a member of the EFTA and CPTPP simultaneously?

Tags: european-union, brexit, efta, cptpp

Theoretically, is there any law or arrangement that would prevent the UK from being  part of the European Free Trade Association and the Comprehensive and Progressive Agreement for Trans-Pacific Partnership simultaneously. Are there any immediate problems with this?

Comment: EFTA and/or CPTPP might include stipulations about a common trade policy which might prevent mutual membership. Or different required standards and procedures might just pose too many practical problems. But apart from that I think that both allow third-country trade arrangements.